# Manually authentication in Spring Security with Oauth2 does not persist SecurityContext throughout the session

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security Oauth2 with JWT for login/authorization of a Client application to an Authorization Server application, both built with Spring Boot 2.

In the Client application I am doing the login manually, retrieving the JWT token from the Authorization Server and then doing in the code

```
OAuth2Authentication authentication = tokenStore.readAuthentication(token);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

The problem that I have is that I want to retrieve the token later in the flow of the application, but SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null. This tells me that SecurityContext gets cleared at some point by Spring.

How can I make somehow for the SecurityContext to be persistent along the entire session? Or what am I doing wrong?

Some snippets of the configuration that I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf()
      .disable()
      .sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated();
  }
...
}
```

Then I want to retrieve the token later in the flow of the Client app:

```
 SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
 OAuth2Authentication oauth = (OAuth2Authentication)securityContext.getAuthentication();
 String token = (String) oauth.getCredentials();
```

but oauth object is null.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a session afterwards and update it's context?

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
```